# xml deserialization not working with soap xml .net

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, soap, xml-deserialization

I have the following soap xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://xxx.xxx/soap-encoding/Tester/">
<soap:Body>
<m:EventInst xmlns="http://xxx.xxx/soap-encoding/Tester/EventInst" soap:id="123">
<m:Occurances soap:href="3553||3" />
<m:Subject xsi:type="xsd:string">Subject Value</m:Subject>
<m:StateRef xsi:type="xsd:string">1234</m:StateRef>
<m:Type xsi:type="xsd:string">ABC</m:Type>
<m:Message xsi:type="xsd:string"> Message</m:Message>
</m:EventInst>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am using this xml content and getting the respective xml classes in VS using the option Edit-Paste Special -> Paste XML as Classes. 
The class is generated and I am trying to deserialize the xml using the class but it is giving values for the Occurances only . The other fields like the Subject ,StateRef Type are null.

```
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Resources.XML);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            var objectxml= (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

        }
```

Can someone help me out please. 
Envelope model is :

```
'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope", IsNullable:=False)> _
Partial Public Class Envelope

    Private bodyField As EnvelopeBody

    Private encodingStyleField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property Body() As EnvelopeBody
        Get
            Return Me.bodyField
        End Get
        Set(value As EnvelopeBody)
            Me.bodyField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)> _
    Public Property encodingStyle() As String
        Get
            Return Me.encodingStyleField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.encodingStyleField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope")> _
Partial Public Class EnvelopeBody

    Private eventInstField As EventInst

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:="http://xxx.xxx/soap-encoding/Tester/")> _
    Public Property EventInst() As EventInst
        Get
            Return Me.eventInstField
        End Get
        Set(value As EventInst)
            Me.eventInstField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="http://xxx.xxx/soap-encoding/Tester/"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="http://xxx.xxx/soap-encoding/Tester/", IsNullable:=False)> _
Partial Public Class EventInst

    Private occurancesField As EventInstOccurances

    Private subjectField As EventInstSubject

    Private stateRefField As EventInstStateRef

    Private typeField As EventInstType

    Private messageField As EventInstMessage

    Private idField As Byte

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property Occurances() As EventInstOccurances
        Get
            Return Me.occurancesField
        End Get
        Set(value As EventInstOccurances)
            Me.occurancesField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property Subject() As EventInstSubject
        Get
            Return Me.subjectField
        End Get
        Set(value As EventInstSubject)
            Me.subjectField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property StateRef() As EventInstStateRef
        Get
            Return Me.stateRefField
        End Get
        Set(value As EventInstStateRef)
            Me.stateRefField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property Type() As EventInstType
        Get
            Return Me.typeField
        End Get
        Set(value As EventInstType)
            Me.typeField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property Message() As EventInstMessage
        Get
            Return Me.messageField
        End Get
        Set(value As EventInstMessage)
            Me.messageField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, [Namespace]:="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope")> _
    Public Property id() As Byte
        Get
            Return Me.idField
        End Get
        Set(value As Byte)
            Me.idField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="http://xxx.xxx/soap-encoding/Tester/")> _
Partial Public Class EventInstOccurances

    Private hrefField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, [Namespace]:="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope")> _
    Public Property href() As String
        Get
            Return Me.hrefField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.hrefField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="http://xxx.xxx/soap-encoding/Tester/")> _
Partial Public Class EventInstSubject

    Private typeField As String

    Private valueField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, [Namespace]:="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance")> _
    Public Property type() As String
        Get
            Return Me.typeField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.typeField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()> _
    Public Property Value() As String
        Get
            Return Me.valueField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.valueField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="http://xxx.xxx/soap-encoding/Tester/")> _
Partial Public Class EventInstStateRef

    Private typeField As String

    Private valueField As UShort

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, [Namespace]:="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance")> _
    Public Property type() As String
        Get
            Return Me.typeField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.typeField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()> _
    Public Property Value() As UShort
        Get
            Return Me.valueField
        End Get
        Set(value As UShort)
            Me.valueField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="http://xxx.xxx/soap-encoding/Tester/")> _
Partial Public Class EventInstType

    Private typeField As String

    Private valueField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, [Namespace]:="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance")> _
    Public Property type() As String
        Get
            Return Me.typeField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.typeField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()> _
    Public Property Value() As String
        Get
            Return Me.valueField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.valueField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="http://xxx.xxx/soap-encoding/Tester/")> _
Partial Public Class EventInstMessage

    Private typeField As String

    Private valueField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, [Namespace]:="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance")> _
    Public Property type() As String
        Get
            Return Me.typeField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.typeField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()> _
    Public Property Value() As String
        Get
            Return Me.valueField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.valueField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: `it is giving out errors because of the soap contents`. Would you share those errors with us if they are not top-secret?

Comment: Exception Message :{"There is an error in XML document (2, 2)."}         Inner Exception:"<Envelope xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope'> was not expected."}

Comment: Can you post your model as well? (The `Envelope` class)

Comment: Added envelope model